# How can I install gcc-libc6-dev in opensolaris?

Tags: gcc, libc, opensolaris

when I am doing `./configure` in opensolaris in an attempt to install software. I've got the following error:

```
error:C compiler cannot create executables
```

Then I check up on the net and find its due to a missing module call `gcc-lib6-dev`. But how can I install it?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you found an answer for a completely different OS that doesn't apply to opensolaris (lib6 sounds like an old Linux release).   Look in the generated config.log 
for more detailed error messages that give better information as to the actual problem.